# How to find the product of each row in a list of lists?

Tags: python

Say I have a list of lists:

```
list = [[2, 4, 3, 8], 
        [5, 6, 4, 3], 
        [1, 9, 5, 7],
        [8, 3, 1, 2]]
```

What I'm trying to do is get the product of each row and column without duplication.

So I would get the product of row 1 and row 2 (2*5, 4*6, 3*4, 8*3), then the product of row 1 and row 3 (2*1, 4*9, 3*5, 8*7), then product of row 1 and row 4 (2*8, 4*3, 3*1, 8*2).

After row 1 is complete, move on to row 2 and get the product of row 2 and row 3 (5*1, 6*9, 4*5, 3*7), then the product of row 2 and 4 (5*8, 6*3, 4*1, 3*2).

Lastly, we do row 3 and row 4 (1*8, 9*3, 5*1, 7*2)

I'm trying to figure out how to do this with loops, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy` and `itertools.combinations`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

>>> [np.array(i)*j for i,j in combinations(li,2)]
[array([10, 24, 12, 24]), array([ 2, 36, 15, 56]), array([16, 12,  3, 16]), array([ 5, 54, 20, 21]), array([40, 18,  4,  6]), array([ 8, 27,  5, 14])]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> zip(*(tuple(x * y for x, y in itertools.combinations(row, 2)) for row in zip(*LL)))
[(10, 24, 12, 24), (2, 36, 15, 56), (16, 12, 3, 16), (5, 54, 20, 21), (40, 18, 4, 6), (8, 27, 5, 14)]
```

Comment: Nice to see such a turn-out for a gimme codez question.

Comment: That's why I stick to answers that no sane professor would ever think came from the student. And if they do then I've planted a ticking time bomb which will explode decades later, leading to the student's death from stress.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (Python 2.7, replace `xrange` by `range` if you are using Python 3)

```
list = [[2, 4, 3, 8], 
        [5, 6, 4, 3], 
        [1, 9, 5, 7],
        [8, 3, 1, 2]]

def multiply_rows(a, b):
    # Assuming all rows are the same length.
    return [a[i] * b[i] for i in xrange(0, len(a))] 

for i in xrange(0, len(list)): # Iterate through all the rows
    for j in xrange(i+1, len(list)): # Making sure not to multiply the same rows twice
        print(multiply_rows(list[i], list[j]))
```

Answer (score 0):

An explicit solution without importing any module is

```
[[x*y for x, y in zip(rowx, rowy)]
 for ix, rowx in enumerate(L)
 for rowy in L[ix+1:]]
```

but of course it has three "loops", one for the product of two rows and two nested ones for getting all possible pairings of distinct rows.

They're list comprehension loops, but still loops.

PS: never call a list `list` in Python code. That would hide the name of a system type and (badly) surprise programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Even other solutions are great, but if you are a beginner this will be a great help.

```
from itertools import izip #faster than zip
from operator import mul
my_list=[[2, 4, 3, 8], 
        [5, 6, 4, 3], 
        [1, 9, 5, 7],
        [8, 3, 1, 2]]
final_list=[]
for n,i in izip(*my_list):
    final_list.append(reduce(mul,i,1))

print final_list
```